# PHP: Redirect ( header)

Tags: php

```
header("profil.php?id=" . $show["id"]);
```

What i tried to do, but headers are already sent at top, so how can I redirect the user? Should I use window.location.replace("URL"); (javascript) instead?

Comment: Can you include (some of) your script in your question? We might be able to spot why the headers are being sent before your call to `header()`.

Comment: Hello. I have two files at top. First one is dbc.php, that holds all functions inclusive some headers and so. And then the top.php comes, that contains html. So thats where using headers later in the file (like I want to) gets this error.

Comment: You know, you can do yourself a huge favor, by just pasting here an exact error message, that contain a lot of useful information.

Answer (score 4):

If you can't control the very beginning of the script, where headers would be sent, then yes, your only method is to use JavaScript.

Also, the proper syntax is `header('Location: profil.php?id=' . $show['id']);`

You need the `Location:` part so the browser knows what header it's receiving. Also, don't forget to do an `exit()` or `die()` right after the redirect.

Answer (score 1):

Someone correct me if i'm wrong, but I think you can use `ob_start()` at the beginning of your page and that will allow you to redirect via PHP even if headers are already sent.

Comment: Yes, you are wrong. To make a proper application structure is way better than using a crutch.

Comment: Upvote, because `output buffering` is indeed the quick fix in this scenario. `ob_start();` and `ob_clean();`. Would be better to separate code and html so you can make sure your headers will always be sent before output.. but otherwise, buffer your output!

Comment: Yeah Col. Shrapnel, I know.. unfortunately that's what most people are looking for. I did add a hint for what would be a better solution tho, giving them the option to either do it right - or go for the duct tape fix. The rest, is up to the person reading it.

Comment: Im not looking for that at all. Please read my comment in the question, i explained why I get headers already sent..

Comment: @user457827 Best way: code separation, with headers and a small text in html after the headers if for some magic reason the browser failed to use them. Other ways would be headers but with output buffering like said, or javascript (which is not good for javascript-disabled people, they exist), or a `<meta>` redirect.

Answer (score 1):

You should redesign your application, to make it more sensible.
It should start output only when it necessary, not just every time this file is called.

You have to modify all your code by dividing every script to 2 parts. First part will contain all data manipulations and second will contain output only. It will be better to put the latter one into separate file, called template. thus your profiles php will looks like

```
include 'dbc.php';
//some code that sends headers, gets data etc
//after it's all done, call your template files
include 'top.php';
include 'profiles.tpl.php';
include 'bottom.php';
```

there can be some variations, but the main idea would be the same: separate your data manipulation from data presentation.

Comment: I have two files at top. First one is dbc.php, that holds all functions inclusive some headers and so. And then the top.php comes, that contains html. So thats where using headers later in the file (like I want to) gets this error. So if I use php then html then php again, then it will header error

Comment: @user457827 so **don't have 2 files at top!** But have your dbc.php only and make it to do no output. And call your header file later in the script, where actual output starts.

Comment: So you say that i should call top.php IN dbc.php? Or? And in dbc.php contains some headers() but all has die(); after.

Comment: @user457827 hell no. not in dbc.php

Comment: Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at top.php:70) in profiles.php on line 280 (this line, there's the header I made for redirecting user). Line 70 in top.php is just <?php

Comment: Ooh i think it get it. i include dbc.php first, and thats clean php. Then in top.php there comes the html, meta, <head</head><body..and then at line 70 little php code part starts, and it takes that as a headers already sent.. So how would i fix that?

Comment: **output started at top.php:70** see, it's top.php. and it should be called below line 280 of profiles.php. **OR** the code, responsible for this redirect, should be moved higher.

Comment: Would i need to modify ALL my code, so every PHP code i got be on top, and then html after.. I cant combine them two?! Well then in the middle of code i cant even do if($blabla){ echo "admin link"; } (example)

Comment: OK i even tried to remove the whole include "top.php" now i got output started at profiles.php:279 (the header('Location: profil.php?id=' . $show["id"]); line)

Comment: I hope i am not annoying you i really try to understand

Comment: @user457827 no, at line 70 not PHP code starts, but output starts. You have to modify all your code by dividing every script to 2 parts. see update to my post

Comment: Okay.. how can output start at line 70 in top.php, when there's no header() in there at all, only a <?php and then after if(isset($_SESSION['user_id'])) { ..

Comment: @user457827 `header()` function don't do output. `echo` does.

Comment: WOW, this is really confusing. echo? yes, but i have no echo at line 70?! And your updated answer i dont quite get it either, you say after the dbc.php I should have the stuff that do header and so.

Comment: This is really really hard for me to understand still. My situation is so that in profiles.php LATER(at line 157) i have a $_GET that check for if you have searched something. Have you yes/no, make query, select and such, if there's only ONE that fully matches and are equal to what you have searched 100% then header to the user´s profile.

Comment: Now, with what you are saying, i would need to check if get at the top, and make a query at the top, and check at the top( BEFORE the top.php)? That would make everything complicated, whenever im coding, so i would always need to have everything at the top(after the dbc.php and before the top.php) and then make another check again for $_get if i want to echo something at line 157

Comment: Another issue by putting everything at the top, my while() that checks if fullname is equal to what you have searched, wont apply at the top.. should i just use javascript?

Comment: @user457827 every loop's results can stored in an array and used later. But may be you are right, may be it's too complicated for you. But as a matter of fact, you can make things easier by structuring your code properly

Answer (score 0):

I see it that you have two options

1) You try to ensure that your headers are not set until after you have executed your code. Your headers being set before you have even determined what you are sending back to the user suggests your code is a little messy, or you are constrained in some way.

2) You can use your javascript solution. However, I would consider this as a hack, rather than an appropriate solution. Try to figure out the answer to why you can't use approach 1.

EDIT: A code example added

Your code should look something like this

```
<?php

// perform logic to determine if you need to do the redirect or not.
// if you do need to redirect, set the following 
$iNeedToRedirect = true;
// if you do not need to redirect, set the following
$iNeedToRedirect = false;

if ($iNeedToRedirect) {
   header("Location: profil.php?id=" . $show["id"]");
   die();
}

// if code gets here, carry on as normal
include("dbc.php");
include("top.php");

... etc etc etc
?>
```

Comment: Hello. I have two files at top. First one is dbc.php, that holds all functions inclusive some headers and so. And then the top.php comes, that contains html. So thats where using headers later in the file (like I want to) gets this error.

Comment: In which case, I would suggest performing your logic that checks if you need to perform a redirect before you include the top.html. The top can come immediately after (so, if you have used the redirect, then use exit() or die() as someone else has mentioned to not process any more of the php file).

Comment: Dont know if it matters, but in dbc.php i got some header() but they all have die(); after.

Comment: You say I should make the header at the top, but how should i activate the header(), later on in the code?

Comment: @user457827 no, it doesn't matter. it's top.php responsible for this problem. but to be certain it would be very nice to see the actual error message instead of listening to your story of 2 files.

Comment: @user457827 - I have edited my answer to show you how a code example of how it should work.

Comment: Yes i get that, ok, but how do call and use iNeedToRedirect later in that code? I mean I have an if statement, and if that is true then it should header(), how do i "activate" iNeedToRedirect then there? Can you do that in php? (go back and activate) or wouldnt you need to make it as a function or something..

Comment: @user457827 You don't. It is actioned immediately before anything else. To prevent your code from breaking, you must ensure that you send the redirect before ANY other HTML or Header is sent.

Comment: What? I think you misunderstood me. How do i tell to iNeedToRedirect that YES, so it can run the header()??

Comment: At the top of the PHP file, before any of your includes, perform the logic that decides if you need to redirect. If you do, then set the variable iNeedToRedirect = true. I'll update the code so you can see what I mean.

Comment: Yes you see, thats where the issue is at. I have the code LATER in the file, so i can not set the variable later and then it will check for it.. understand?

Comment: Yes, I understand, but all that means is you move the code I have shown in the example later on in the php file, and ensure that you do not output any HTML or headers until after you have determined if you need to redirect or not. If you really can't do this, then the only options you have is the javascript route, which is a hack, but if you really cant do this the right way, it does show up a big design flaw in you code and you should consider refactoring your code.

Comment: There is no other way, because also the if statement i talked about is to check INSIDE an while() if the user´s fullname is equal to what you searched and if it is it should redirect you. And you cant move your while() to the top, as ofcourse then the "profile´s list" that are made by the while() will not appear where i want it to appear.

Answer (score 0):

From the [`header` documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.header.php):

> Remember that header() must be called before any actual output is sent, either by normal HTML tags, blank lines in a file, or from PHP. It is a very common error to read code with include(), or require(), functions, or another file access function, and have spaces or empty lines that are output before header() is called. The same problem exists when using a single PHP/HTML file.

The headers are being sent before your call to `header()` due to output from the script. You just need to track down where the output is coming from.